# Creating a specific type of object chosen from a set of types obtained through reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm essentially coding an interface for a user to create instances of different classes. I'm using winforms so that if the code says the class has a property of type int, it provides a numbox, a check box for bool, etc. The form is generated at runtime and the controls shown depends on the number and type of the properties in the class being reflected upon.

I need to take the values the user inputs and create an object with the properties set to those values. The issue is that the number and types of the properties is different for each object. What I'd like is some way to do the following:

```
Object o = new Object(property1, property2)
```

Where Object would be replaced by whatever class is currently being used and the parameters are replaced with the values from the winform controls in the appropriate quantity.

The type that the class could be is limited to a finite list, and each class has a constructor in the style above. All classes have at least one property to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<object> parms = new List<object>();
parms.Add(property1);
parms.Add(property2);

ObjectHandle objHandle = Activator.CreateInstance("assemblyName", "className", false, null, null, parms.ToArray(), null, null );

object workingObject = objHandle.Unwrap();
```

Replace "assemblyName" with your assembly's name and "className" with the fully-qualified name of your class.
This should give you the flexability to create an instance of any class with any number of constructor parameters.

Comment: So it turns out my constructors don't actually work as nicely as I'd hoped (and it's not my code so I can't change them so they do) but based on the errors I'm getting, had they worked as expected your answer would have been perfect.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand, 
you need to have a factory class that will create and assign the properties
Following info may help.
to the factory class method you need to pass the following info

1. type of class/control needed ( as you mentioned int or bool, any thing is fine as long as your factory class understands this logic) 
   i.e it can create the control needed either by reflection or by simply instantiating the class
2. for passing the properties info i suggest to have a dictionary of type string,object 
   .string will store the property name  as key and Object as its value

for assigning the properties values, you loop through this dictionary 
and assign values using reflection as shown in the below sample

> Type type = control.GetType();
>
> PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("propertyName");
>
> prop.SetValue (control,propertyValue, null);

if my understanding is not right, please add more info on your question in the comments